# Is it Possible to Install Part of Python Package Via Pip?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have an internal utility library that is used by many projects. There is quite a bit of overlap between the projects in the code they pull from the utility library, but as the library grows, so does the amount of extra stuff any individual project gets that it won't be using. This wouldn't be an issue if the library consisted of only python, but the library also bundles in binaries.

Example-

**psycopg2** is used in a handful of places within the utility library, but not all projects need db access. Because the development environment isn't the same as the production environment, the utility library also includes psycopg2 binaries for the prod environment.

This grows with openssl libraries, pandas, numpy, scipy, pyarrow, etc. The result is that a small, 50 line, single purpose script that may need db access is bundled into a 100mb+ deployment package.

[image]

So what I'd like to do is carve up the utility library into pieces where the projects down stream can choose which pieces to pull in, but keep the utility library code in one easy-to-manage place. That way, this small single purpose application can choose to import `internal-util@core`, `internal-util@db` and not include `internal-util@numpy` and `internal-util@openssl`

[image]

Is what i'm describing possible to do?

Comment: I know that you don't want to split the library but it kind of goes against the whole philosophy of python module system. We have one simple way of importing modules, and if we don't want something to be imported as a whole we split it into parts. Is the library literary a single file full of numerous small utilities? If so, it would be an obvious candidate to split in line with single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 10):

Not directly, to my best knowledge. `pip` installs a package fully, or not at all.

However, if you're careful in your package about how you import things that may require `psycopg2` or `someotherlargebinarything`, you could use the [`extras_require`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras) feature and thus have the package's users choose which dependencies they want to pull in:

```
setup(
  # ...
  name='myawesometoolbelt',
  extras_require={
    'db': ['psycopg2'],
    'math': ['numpy'],
  },
)
```

and then, in your `requirements.txt`, or `pip` invocation,

```
myawesometoolbelt[db,math]
```

Comment: can i use the local modules which are part of the library to optionally get included in the pip install by using extras_require?

Answer (score -2):

You should try looking at `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Once you generated your pip list via pip freeze, it is possible to edit which packages you want installed and which to omit from the `requirements.txt` generated.
You can then `pip install -r requirements.txt` the things you want back in.